# Batch-altering edges in igraph graph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to augment the adjacency matrix of an [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net) graph. I tried the following with no success:

```
require(igraph)
require(Matrix)
set.seed(123) # to get always the same graph (see "R reproducible example")
G <- igraph::erdos.renyi.game(20,10,type="gnm")
mat <- Matrix(1:16, ncol=4,nrow=4)
G[1:4, 1:4] <- mat
# Error in `[<-.igraph`(`*tmp*`, 1:4, 1:4, value = <S4 object of class "dgeMatrix">) : 
# New value should be NULL, numeric or logical
```

Also tried:
    G[1:4, 1:4] <- as.numeric(mat)

```
# Error in `[<-.igraph`(`*tmp*`, 1:4, 1:4, value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, :
# Logical or numeric value must be of length 1
```

I know about the [add.edges()](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graph.structure.html) function, but it seems that would not replace the edges, but instead append to weight? If I am wrong about that, please correct me as well.

I'm new to `R` so feel free to be as verbose as necessary.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here? What do you mean by "replacing edges"? If you want to remove the edges among vertices 1:4, and add the ones present in the matrix, then just do that, use `delete.edges()` and `add.edges().

Comment: By 'replacing the edges' I effectively meant remove and replace edge weights with new weights, just in a single more efficient step. When I say efficient, I mean only update the index to the nodes in positions that require it as opposed to remove all, then add all in the submatrix I want. I guess this might be slow since the index to nodes must be updated twice for all nodes in the submatrix?

Comment: If the edges are already all present, then just update their weights. This can be done with `G[from=..., to=...] <- newweigths`. You cannot add edges and update weights of other edges in a single step. You cannot delete edges and add edges in a single step, either. Btw. adding weights does not change internal igraph indices, but in R it does copy the whole graph once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment `G[] <-` takes only one logical value (i.e. `TRUE` or `FALSE`) as stated in the documentation.
(type:

```
?`[<-.igraph`
```

and check section "The indexing operators")

So, for example if you create a graph in this way:

```
require(igraph)
set.seed(144) # just to get the same initial graph
G <- igraph::erdos.renyi.game(10,5,type="gnm")

plot.igraph(G,layout=layout.kamada.kawai)
```

[image: Initial Graph]

then you do:

```
G[1:4,1:4]
>
[1,] . . . .
[2,] . . 1 .
[3,] . 1 . .
[4,] . . . .
```

You get a `4x4` sparse matrix of `(0,1)`, where `1` at position `(i,j)` indicates that there's an edge from `i` to `j`.
As you can see, in this case there's only one edge `2,3` (and obviously `3,2` since is an undirected graph)

Then, by setting `G[1:4,1:4] <- TRUE` you're forcing an edge between all vertices in `(1,4)`, conversely, by setting `G[1:4,1:4] <- FALSE` you're deleting all edges between all vertices in `(1,4)`.

Hence, these methods are not very well suited to "batch altering" the adjacency matrix selectively, since you can only create or delete all edges in a subset of the matrix.

In my opinion, a better approach could be combining this approach with `add.edges`; for example, if you want to change the `(1,4)` adj. submatrix to connect `(1,3)` and `(2,4)`, you could do:

```
G[1:4,1:4] <- FALSE # remove previous edges
G <- add.edges(G, c(1,3,2,4)) # add the new edges
```

In fact, plotting again:

```
plot.igraph(G,layout=layout.kamada.kawai)
```

you'll get this:

[image: Modified Graph]

Where you can see that the edge `(2,3)` has been eliminated and the new edges `(1,3)` and `(2,4)` have been added.

Comment: It seems you are correct. This is the most effective way to do what I need. Thanks!